# Formula if Cell Contains x but Not y in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, contains

I'm looking for help with 2 formulas to add a custom formula in conditional formatting in Google Sheets:

1. counts the number of cells containing the word apple in k2:k100, but does not include cells that contain longer words that contain apple, for example, applepie or sweetapplepie or redapple
2. counts the number of cells containing the word apple in k2:k100, but does not include cells that contain longer words that contain apple, for example, applepie or sweetapplepie or redapple, and does not find the word orange in k2:k100

Comment: To make #2 more clear...applepie, sweetapplepie, and redapple might not always be the words found that contain apple. So the formula needs to recognize a character directly before s and a character directly after o

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, these two formulas should do what you are looking for:

`=if(upper($K2)="APPLE", true, false)`

[image: ex]

`=if((upper($K2)="APPLE")*(upper($L2)="ORANGE"), true, false)`

[image: ex2]

Comment: That's close, but not quite. I'm also needing to exclude apple if apple is contained within another word. To make it more clear...applepie, sweetapplepie, and redapple might not always be the words found that contain apple. So the formula needs to recognize a character directly before s and a character directly after o

Also note that applepie has a space before apple, sweetapplepie has no spaces before and after apple, and redapple has a space after apple

Comment: The formula you gave is working! Thank you! But, I noticed another anomaly.  The word apple may also have a special character or number next to it, e.g., 1apple or 2apple2 or apple/ or /apple/.   In those cases, apple should not be counted. How would you adjust the formula to exclude those cells in the count?

Comment: @ihavequestions The current formulas already accounts for things like that. By setting the formula to include `=if(upper($K2)="APPLE",...` (simplified), you are only going to get cells which include strictly `apple`, no other variations (aside from capital/lowercase, which is accounted for using `UPPER()`)

Comment: Does your formula include both uppercase and lowercase?

Comment: @ihavequestions “ no other variations (aside from capital/lowercase, which is accounted for using UPPER()) ” yes

Comment: Thank you. What if I didn't care about upper/lower case? In this case, I'd like to include all instances upper/lowercase of apple. What would the formula be then?

Comment: @ihavequestions This formula already accounts for that. It includes all uppercase and lowercase variations.